# How to add specific lines from a file into List in Python?

Tags: python, list, readline

I have an input file:

```
3
PPP
TTT
QPQ

TQT
QTT
PQP

QQQ
TXT
PRP
```

I want to read this file and group these cases into proper `boards`.
To read the `Count` (no. of boards) i have code:

```
board = []
count =''    
def readcount():
        fp = open("input.txt")
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i == 0:
                count = int(line)
                break
        fp.close()
```

But i don't have any idea of how to parse these blocks into List:

```
TQT
QTT
PQP
```

I tried using

```
def readboard():
    fp = open('input.txt')
    for c in (1, count): # To Run loop to total no. of boards available
        for k in (c+1, c+3): #To group the boards into board[]
            board[c].append(fp.readlines)
```

But its wrong way. I know basics of List but here i am not able to parse the file.

These boards are in line 2 to 4, 6 to 8 and so on. How to get them into `Lists`?
I want to parse these into `Count` and `Boards` so that i can process them further?

Please suggest

Comment: what is 3?  Is it the number of items per block or the number of blocks?

Comment: update the question. 3 or (Count) is no. of boards in any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your desired outcome. I *think* you want a list of lists.
Assuming that you want boards to be:
[[data,data,data],[data,data,data],[data,data,data]], then you would need to define how to parse your input file... specifically:

- line 1 is the count number
- data is entered per line
- boards are separated by white space.

If that is the case, this should parse your files correctly:

```
board = []
count = 0 
currentBoard = 0 

fp = open('input.txt')
for i,line in enumerate(fp.readlines()):
    if i == 0:
        count = int(i)
        board.append([])
    else:
        if len(line[:-1]) == 0:
            currentBoard += 1
            board.append([])
        else: #this has board data
            board[currentBoard].append(line[:-1])
fp.close()
import pprint
pprint.pprint(board)
```

If my assumptions are wrong, then this can be modified to accomodate.
Personally, I would use a dictionary (or ordered dict) and get the count from len(boards):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
currentBoard = 0
board = {}
board[currentBoard] = []

fp = open('input.txt')
lines = fp.readlines()
fp.close()

for line in lines[1:]:
    if len(line[:-1]) == 0:
        currentBoard += 1
        board[currentBoard] = []
    else:
        board[currentBoard].append(line[:-1])

count = len(board)
print(count)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(board)
```

Comment: The above code worked fine for me and that was what i want. But now to access any element of board say 2nd board 2nd line and 3rd element, I am using "print list(board[1])[1][2]" is that okay? or is there some way to access at Board level only?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by board level only.  You can access the board data as you mentioned (board[1][1][2]), or you can access a board's characters (board[1][1]), or you can access a board's elements (board[1]).  It depends on what your goal is.  If this data represents something specific, perhaps a class would be a more intuitive interface than an array of arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to take specific line numbers and put them into a list:

```
line_nums = [3, 4, 5, 1]
fp = open('input.txt')
[line if i in line_nums for i, line in enumerate(fp)]
fp.close()
```